uses-native-library does not get added to Expo config for plugin
I am trying my first plugin for Android specific so that I can add uses-native-library as per package docs for a setting I need to use related to frame processing.
I created a plugin withUsesNativeLibrary which runs during the prebuild, but I do not see the uses-native-library being added to the application part of the output, which is where it lives according to the Android docs.
// Define the library names you want to add to the AndroidManifest.xml
const nativeLibraries = [
  'libOpenCL.so',
  'libOpenCL-pixel.so',
  'libGLES_mali.so',
  'libPVROCL.so',
];

module.exports = function withUsesNativeLibrary(config) {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, config => {
    const { modResults } = config;

    if (
      !Array.isArray(modResults.manifest.application?.['uses-native-library'])
    ) {
      modResults.manifest.application['uses-native-library'] = [];
    }

    // Add each native library entry
    nativeLibraries.forEach(libraryName => {
      const hasLib = modResults.manifest.application[
        'uses-native-library'
      ].some(lib => {
        return lib['$']['android:name'] === libraryName;
      });

      if (!hasLib) {
        modResults.manifest.application['uses-native-library'].push({
          $: {
            'android:name': libraryName,
            'android:required': 'false',
          },
        });
      }
    });

    //    console.log(modResults.manifest.application['uses-native-library']);


    return config;
  });
};

If I log console.log(modResults.manifest.application['uses-native-library']); before the return, the result looks ok, I think:
[
  {
    '$': { 'android:name': 'libOpenCL.so', 'android:required': 'false' }
  },
  {
    '$': {
      'android:name': 'libOpenCL-pixel.so',
      'android:required': 'false'
    }
  },
  {
    '$': { 'android:name': 'libGLES_mali.so', 'android:required': 'false' }
  },
  {
    '$': { 'android:name': 'libPVROCL.so', 'android:required': 'false' }
  }
]

So it seems like it's there, but when I log the full config it's not there, so is it being stripped out?
Am I handling adding it to the config correctly?  Does the uses-native-library not work with Expo?
Thanks
